# C Programming 'Craps' Game

Tags: c, random, numbers, generator

I'm doing a learning task for my C programming course, I've been asked to do the following:

> **Task 2. Craps.**
>
> In the game of Craps, a "Pass Line" bet proceeds as follows. Using two six-sided dice,
>   the first roll of the dice in a craps round is called the "Come out Roll." The bet
>   immediately wins when the come out roll is 7 or 11, and loses when the come out roll is
>   2, 3, or 12. If 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10 is rolled on the come out roll, that number becomes "the point." The player keeps rolling the dice until either 7 or the point is rolled. If the point is rolled first, then the player wins the bet. If the player rolls a 7 first, then the player
>   loses.
>
> Write a program that plays the game of Craps using the rules stated above so that it
>   simulates a game without human input. Instead of asking for a wager, the program
>   should just calculate if the player would win or lose. Create a function that simulates
>   rolling the two dice and returns the sum. Add a loop so that the program plays 10,000
>   games.
>
> Add counters that count how many times the player wins, and how many times
>   the player loses. At the end of the 10,000 games, compute the probability of winning, i.e.
>   Wins / (Wins + Losses) and output this value. Over the long run, who is going to win
>   the most games of Craps, you or the house?

Here is what I have written so far:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>

// Craps Program
// Written by Kane Charles
// Lab 2 - Task 2

// 7 or 11 indicates instant win
// 2, 3 or 12 indicates instant los
// 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 on first roll becomes "the point"
// keep rolling dice until either 7 or "the point is rolled"
//      if "the point" is rolled the player wins
//      if 7 is rolled then the player loses

    int wins = 0, losses = 0;
    int r, i;
    int N = 1, M = 12;
    int randomgenerator();

main(void){

    /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));
  /* generate random number 10,000 times: */
  for(i=0; i < 10000 ; i++){
     int r = randomgenerator();
     if (r == 7 || r == 11) {
        wins++;
     }
     else if (r == 2 || r == 3 || r == 12) {
        losses++;
     }
     else if (r == 4 || r == 5 || r == 6 || r == 8 || r == 9 || r == 10) {
        int point = r;
        int temproll;
        int *tr = &temproll;
        do
        {
             *tr = randomgenerator();

        }while (temproll != 7 || temproll != point);

        if (temproll == 7) {
            losses++;
        }
        else if (temproll == point) {
            wins++;
        }
     }
  }
    printf("Wins\n");
    printf("%d",&wins);
    printf("\nLosses\n");
    printf("%d",&losses);
}

int randomgenerator(){
    r = M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1);
    return r;
}
```

The program always ends with:

```
Wins:
0.000000
Losses:
0.000000
```

Whereas it is supposed to show (out of 10000) how many times the program won and how many times it lost. Is anybody able to help me out with this please? I suspect I might need to use pointers instead of `wins++` and `losses++` so that the scores are kept globally.

Keep in mind I'm new to a lot of this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rolling two six sided dice doesn't generate an evenly weighted probability between 2 and 12.  You're passing mismatched values to your print statement, which is why you end up with the `0` printouts - turn up your warning levels!

Comment: Please don't edit your question like that.  It makes people's answers nonsensical.  You can feel free to *add* new information, but please don't replace what was there to begin with.

Comment: @CarlNorum sorry about that, I didn't even think about how this would look for people viewing the post. Sorry again

Answer (score 5):

I see one major issue with your `if` statements in `main` for example:

```
if (r = 7 || 11)
```

you are using `=` assignment instead of `==` equality. The next problem is that you seem to have a misunderstanding about how `||` works. It looks like you want to check if `r` is either `7` or `11` which would actually be:

```
if( (r == 7) || (r == 11) )
```

You are also creating a local `temproll` in your `do` loop here:

```
 int temproll;
 do
 {
      int temproll = randomgenerator();
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 }while (temproll != 7 || point);
```

which mean that value you generate in the `do` loop is lost once you leave and the subsequent `if` statements will be checking an undefined value. As far as I can tell you probably meant the `while` to be this:

```
 while (temproll != 7 && temproll != r );
```

which means while `temproll` is not `7` and it is not `r`.

Also the wins and losses print out at the end needs to be fixed:

```
printf("%lf",&wins);
printf("%lf",&losses);
```

the `lf` format is for `double` and you are taking the address of `wins` instead of the value, it should be:

```
printf("%d",wins);
printf("%d",losses);
```

Comment: +1.  And `||` doesn't work like that.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yeah, I posted before I meant to

Comment: That's not how boolean || works either. r==2 || r==3...

Comment: so would (r==2 || r==3) work? @JoeFrambach

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of logical errors in you code

```
 if (r == 7 || r ==11) {
    //^^^^should be logical equal not assignment and r== cannot be skipped for 11
    wins++;
 }
 else if (r = 2 || 3 || 12) {
  //similar error as above
    losses++;
 }
 else if (r = 4 || 5 || 6 || 8 || 9 || 10) {
  //similar error as above
    int point = r;
    int temproll;
    do
    {
         int temproll = randomgenerator();

    }while (temproll != 7 || point); //^^same error here

    if (temproll = 7) {
        //^^should be temproll ==7
        losses++;
    }
    else if (temproll = point) {
        //similar error
        wins++;
    }
```

After your updates, one issue is here:

```
    int temproll;
    //remove line below
    //int *tr = &temproll;
    do
    {
         //*tr = randomgenerator();
         //replace this line with:
         temproll = randomgenerator();

    }while (temproll != 7 || temproll != point);
```

The print statements for win and loss has error:

```
 printf("%d",&wins);
 //^^^^^^^^^^^remove &
 printf("\nLosses\n");
   printf("%d",&losses);
  ///^^^^^^^^^same thing, remove &
```

Your current code will never end since you have dead loop here:

```
 else if (r == 4 || r == 5 || r == 6 || r == 8 || r == 9 || r == 10) {
    int point = r;  //so r cannot be 7, otherwise, will not enter this if block
    int temproll;
    int *tr = &temproll;
    do
    {
         *tr = randomgenerator();

    }while (temproll != 7 || temproll != point);
    //you will need temproll ==7 and temproll ==point to exit this loop
    //this means point ==7. however, pointer can never be 7. dead loop, keep running...
 }
```

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, they are logical errors, so I updated. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that, I will update code now!

Comment: Do you have any resources that you would recommend for me to use to learn some basic C? Uni hasn't been much help with recommending credible sources to get the basics down. @tacp

Comment: @KaneCharles try to read the canonical book written by Dennis Ritchie: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628

Comment: Thanks for that, will look for a pdf. I've updated my code with the changes you guys have all recommended, could you please have a look over it briefly @tacp ?

Comment: @KaneCharles still some issues, please see update to my answer

Comment: It doesn't finish executing when I run it, it is like there is some sort of infinite loop happening? @tacp or perhaps it takes a long time to complete because it's doing 10000 calculations?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, I forgot to remove the ampersand symbols. It still won't finish execution, weird :/

Comment: Editing now @ShafikYaghmour, will report back soon. Thanks guys

Comment: You guys were spot on, the while statement was meant to be `&&` instead of `||`, thanks heaps!

Comment: @KaneCharles see my updated post? you have dead loop in your code

Comment: @tacp I have fixed the code, it now runs and gives different results each time, however the wins and losses are still fairly close to 5000 each, eg: 4945 wins, 5055 losses. People have mentioned that the way I'm generating random numbers isn't really random enough and that could be why I'm getting results like this, would they be right?

Comment: @KaneCharles you used uniform random, so they should be almost equal

Comment: @tacp do you have a suggestion that I could look into to make it more random?

Comment: @KaneCharles rand() is uniform random, you may look up other C rand functions.